# Given $(x_n)$ with $x_1 = 1, x_{n + 1} = x_n + \frac{1}{(\sqrt m - 1)x_n}$, find all $m$ such that $\lfloor mx_{m^2}\rfloor = m^2$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Given sequence $(x_n)$ satisfying $$ x_1 = 1, x_{n + 1} = x_n + \frac{1}{(\sqrt m - 1)x_n}, \forall n \ge 1$$
>
> Find all positive integer $m$ $(m > 1)$ such that $$ \lfloor mx_{m^2}\rfloor = m^2$$

We have that $$x_1 = 1, x_2 = \dfrac{\sqrt m}{\sqrt m - 1}, x_3 = \dfrac{m + \sqrt m - 1}{\sqrt m(\sqrt m - 1)}, x_4 = \dfrac{m^2 + 3\sqrt{m^3} - 2m - 2\sqrt m + 1}{(\sqrt m - 1)\sqrt m(m - \sqrt m + 1)}, \cdots$$

There doesn't seem to be any patterns here.

It could also be observed that $m = 1$ is the obvious solution.

I have also been told that $m = 9$ is a solution.

I wonder which certain values of $m = p^2$ $(p \in \mathbb Z^+)$ satisfy the condition above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly not.  For $m=4$, $\lfloor 4 x_4 \rfloor = 23$.  It is true that $m=9$ works.
Numerical experiments (using floating-point approximations as the exact values of $x_n$
rapidly get out of hand) seem to show that $x_{m^2}$ grows more slowly than $m$ as $m$ increases.   I suspect that suitable bounds could prove this.

**EDIT**: Consider the iteration $x_{n+1} = x_n + \dfrac{a}{x_n}$ where $x_1 = 1$ and $0 < a \le 1$.
Note that  $$x_{n+1}^2 = x_n^2 + 2 a + \frac{a^2}{x_n^2} \le x_n^2 + 2 a + a^2$$
By induction, $x_n \le \sqrt{1 + (2a+a^2) (n-1)}$. 
In our case we have $a = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt m - 1}$, so
$$ m x_{m^2} \le m\sqrt {1+ \left(  \left( \sqrt {m}-1 \right) ^{-2}+2\, \left( \sqrt {
m}-1 \right) ^{-1} \right)  \left( {m}^{2}-1 \right) }
$$
and this is less than $m^2$ if $m > (2 + \sqrt{2})^2 \approx 11.65$.

Conclusion: After eliminating other values $\le 11$, $m=1$ and $m=9$ are the only solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$$\large x_1 = 1, x_{n + 1} = x_n + \frac{1}{(\sqrt m - 1)x_n}, \forall n \ge 1$$

usually that last part is implied ... But you could try the following:

$$x_{n + 2} = x_n + \frac{1}{(\sqrt m - 1)x_n} + \frac{1}{(\sqrt m - 1)( x_n + \frac{1}{(\sqrt m - 1)x_n})}, \forall n \ge 1$$

which then simplifies to:

$$x_{n + 2} = x_n + \frac{1}{(\sqrt m - 1)x_n} + \frac{1}{(1+(\sqrt m - 1))x_n}, \forall n \ge 1$$

or further to:

$$x_{n + 2} = x_n + \frac{(1+2(\sqrt m - 1))x_n}{(\sqrt m - 1)^2x_n^2+(\sqrt m - 1)x_n}, \forall n \ge 1$$  You can do this for any gap in index values. or you could decompose your requirement using properties of floor with integr multipliers like : $m[x_m]+\lfloor x_m\rfloor m=\lfloor mx_m\rfloor $